# How To Find all Stored Procedure that are using a specific function

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Hello is there a way that I can easily find all stored procedure in SQL Server that are using a specific function like for ex. function `fn_Test()`?

I want to see all the stored procedures using this function.

Thanks

Comment: There is a third party tool thats free. I have used this a lot and it has saved me: http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/

Comment: select * from sys.syscomments where text like '%fn_Test%'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you are after, it will return any sproc with the entered text within it somewhere:

```
SELECT DISTINCT so.name
FROM syscomments sc
INNER JOIN sysobjects so ON sc.id=so.id
WHERE sc.TEXT LIKE '%fn_Test%'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use,

```
SELECT obj.Name SPName, sc.TEXT SPText
FROM sys.syscomments sc
INNER JOIN sys.objects obj ON sc.Id = obj.OBJECT_ID
WHERE sc.TEXT LIKE '%' + 'YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME' + '%'
AND TYPE = 'P'
```

Comment: Just to be aware pulling sc.TEXT as well you might get multiple lines per sproc; if the sproc is large then the TEXT is split over multiple rows in syscomments and if the function is used throughout it will show a row for each segment of the TEXT within the sproc that has the function.

Comment: @Simon1979 : you are absolutely right Simon. Just added that TEXT part so that the user can refer the output. :)

Answer (score 0):

This snippet of sql will list all the stored procedures that contain the name of the function. However that could include content in comments. I think this would be adequate for the job though

```
select distinct name from sysobjects
where type = 'P'
and id in (select id from syscomments where text like '%fn_Test%')
order by name
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities.